AttributeError: 'Typed' object has no attribute 'to_tree'
While saving an excel file got via file upload in a html file through flask,
Code:
from flask import *
import xlsxwriter as xw
import xlwings as xwi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods = ['POST'])
def submit():
    if 'f1' in request.files:
        f1 = load_workbook(request.files['f1'], data_only=True, read_only=False, keep_vba=True, rich_text=True)
            
    f1.save('output.xlsx')

Since the error was showing on charts, I tried deleting the existing charts and saving the excel workbook. still the error is same.
from flask import *
import xlsxwriter as xw
import xlwings as xwi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods = ['POST'])
def submit():
    if 'f1' in request.files:
        f1 = load_workbook(request.files['f1'], data_only=True, read_only=False, keep_vba=True, rich_text=True)
    for sheet in f1.worksheets:
        for num, chart in enumerate(sheet._charts):
            del sheet._charts[num]
            
    f1.save('output.xlsx')

I got the following error:
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\SV21242\Desktop\excelAutomate\withFlask\index.py", line 26, in daily
f1.save('output.xlsx')
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 386, in save
save_workbook(self, filename)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
writer.save()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
self.write_data()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 80, in write_data
self._write_charts()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 124, in _write_charts
self._archive.writestr(chart.path[1:], tostring(chart._write()))
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\chart\_chart.py", line 150, in _write
return cs.to_tree()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\chart\chartspace.py", line 193, in to_tree
tree = super(ChartSpace, self).to_tree()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 154, in to_tree
node = obj.to_tree(child_tag)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 154, in to_tree
node = obj.to_tree(child_tag)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\chart\plotarea.py", line 135, in to_tree
return super(PlotArea, self).to_tree(tagname)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 146, in to_tree
for node in nodes:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 114, in to_tree
el = v.to_tree(namespace=namespace)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\chart\_chart.py", line 110, in to_tree
return super(ChartBase, self).to_tree(tagname, idx)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.1.4-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 154, in to_tree
node = obj.to_tree(child_tag)
AttributeError: 'Typed' object has no attribute 'to_tree'

Sad stuff is I couldn't fine an answer or a related question Stackoverflow or any other websites.
Any help would be greatly helpful

Had this exact issue caused by naming chart trendlines. obj dropped through as a string so didn't have an attribute 'to_tree' at line 154. Presume the same is happening here, i.e. that obj is a string through for a different reason. Trendline naming issue was raised 6 months back and fixed in 3.1. Possibly need your Excel file or how to  create it to determine what's happening here.

Obligatory nitpick: if 'f1' not in request.files you will have a NameError exception.

@moken my openpyxl version is 3.1.4

@Hello World Yes I know, but I don't know what is particular about your workbook

The exception shows that you haven't removed all the charts. ws._charts = [] might be better but note this is a private that can change. If you think there's a bug please submit a bug report with a sample file.
